# Bash Script delete files in directory except those listed in different files

Tags: bash, file, delete-file, rm

I have two files , let's say

```
root@test:~ $ cat File1.txt

name1
name2
name3


root@test:~$ cat File2.txt

name4
name5
name6
```

and a Directory that has several filenames

```
root@test:~$ ls

name1
name2
name3
name4
name5
name6
name7
name8
name9
```

How can I Delete the files which aren't on both .txt files?? so the final result will be

```
root@test:~$ ls
name1
name2
name3
name4
name5
name6
```

is it possible to write something in bash to do this???

Comment: Do you mean delete all files that are not listed in _both_ files? If so step one should be comparing the two files to get the intersection of both text files. I.e. the 'keep these files' list. If you mean in either file - that's the same as having one file with both contents.

Comment: yes, i guess that both ways are pretty similar, i suppose i can join both txt files in one list and then use that to delete the files..

Comment: @MarcosPousada: your question says to delete the files that aren't in *both*, did you mean to ask how to delete files that aren't in *either*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the directory you want to delete the files:

```
for f in *; do
    [ -z $(grep "^${f}$" <(cat /dir/with/File*.txt)) ] && echo rm -f "$f"
done
```

Will print out a list of files to be deleted. To actually delete them, remove the `echo`.

Comment: What about filenames with spaces in them or a filename that is a substring of another filename?

Comment: Filenames with spaces are fine, you are correct about the substring comment - amended answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would test with something like this:

```
while read -r -d $'\0'; do
    if grep -qs "^$REPLY\$" File1 && grep -qs "^$REPLY\$" File2; then
        # Filename found in both File1 and File2: do nothing
        :
    else
        rm -i "$REPLY"
    fi
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0)
```

Unless I'm missing something, this should handle filenames with embedded spaces, newlines, and backslashes correctly.

You can remove the interactive flag (`-i`) from `rm` once you're confident that it's doing what you want.